I have the backup wallet but I forgot the password or password
I have a friend who has a backup wallet of bitcoin core, but she has forgotten her password, the password you use to transfer bitcoins.

This question is similar to: Are there Bitcoin password crackers I can use to recover forgotten passwords?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  See also Who maintains btcrecover?
